# How to set justification on Tkinter Text box

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

**Question**

1. How can I change the justification of specific lines in the `ScrolledText` widget in Tkinter?
2. What was the reason for my original errors?

**Background**

I am currently working on a Tkinter Text box application, and am looking for ways to change the justification of a line. Ultimately, I want to be able to change specific lines from **LEFT ALIGN** to **RIGHT ALIGN** to etc. For now, I simply need to find out how to change the justification of the entire text box, though further help will be greatly appreciated. I have been using Effbot.org to help me in my quest. Here is my code for the `ScrolledText` widget:

**Code**

```
def mainTextFUN(self):
    self.maintextFrame = Frame (root, width = 50, height = 1,
                           )

    self.maintextFrame.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = N, columnspan = 1,
                            rowspan = 1)

    self.write = ScrolledText(self.maintextFrame,
                              justify(CENTER),
                              width = 100, height = 35, relief = SUNKEN,
                              undo = True, wrap = WORD,
                              font = ("Times New Roman",12),
                              )
    self.write.pack()
```

When I run this, I get an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python Programs\Text Editor\MyTextv5.py", line 132, in <module>
    app = Application(root)
  File "D:\Python Programs\Text Editor\MyTextv5.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.mainTextFUN()
File "D:\Python Programs\Text Editor\MyTextv5.py", line 57, in mainTextFUN
justify(CENTER),
NameError: global name 'justify' is not defined
>>>
```

If I change the `justify` argument to after the `font` argument, I get a different error in the form of a messagebox.

```
There's an error in your program:
*** non-keyword arg after keyword arg (MyTextv5.py, line 61)
```

**EDIT**

I changed the code based on a suggestion by abarnert. I added `justify = CENTER,` after `self.maintextFrame`. Despite this, I simply got another error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python Programs\Text Editor\MyTextv5.py", line 132, in <module>
    app = Application(root)
  File "D:\Python Programs\Text Editor\MyTextv5.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.mainTextFUN()
  File "D:\Python Programs\Text Editor\MyTextv5.py", line 60, in mainTextFUN
    font = ("Times New Roman",12),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\ScrolledText.py", line 26, in __init__
    Text.__init__(self, self.frame, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2827, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'text', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1974, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
TclError: unknown option "-justify"
```

Answer (score 15):

You're using an option named `justify`, but no such option exists for the text widget. Are you reading some documentation somewhere that says `justify` is a valid option? If so, you need to stop reading that documentation.

There is, however, a `justify` option for text tags. You can configure a tag to have a justification, then apply that tag to one or more lines. I've never used a `ScrolledText` widget so I don't know if it has the same methods as a plain text widget, but with a plain text widget you would do something like this:

```
t = tk.Text(...)
t.tag_configure("center", justify='center')
t.tag_add("center", 1.0, "end")
```

In the above example, we are creating and configuring a tag named "center". Tags can have any name that you want. For the "center" tag we're giving it a justification of "center", and then applying that tag to all the text in the widget.

You can tag individual lines by adjusting the arguments to the `tag_add` method.  You can also give a list of tags when inserting text using the `insert` method.

Comment: What do you mean by `tags`? Are you saying that that allows me to format the document with greater precision, or something else? In any case, please elaborate further!

Comment: @xxmbabanexx: tags let you associate fonts, colors, margins, justification, baseline offsets, word wrapping and more on a character-by-character and line-by line basis. Search for "Tags" here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm

Answer (score 5):

It is easy to understand why trying to set `justify=CENTER` for a `Text` widget fails: there is no such option for the widget.

What you want is to create a tag with the parameter `justify`. Then you can insert some text using that tag (or you can insert any text and later apply the tag to a certain region):

```
import Tkinter

root = Tkinter.Tk()
text_widget = Tkinter.Text()
text_widget.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

text_widget.tag_configure('tag-center', justify='center')
text_widget.insert('end', 'text ' * 10, 'tag-center')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by `tags`? Are you saying that that allows me to format the document with greater precision, eg.(in SO **  ** allows me to make something **bold**) or something else? In any case, please elaborate further!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your Python syntax, not anything related to `tkinter`:

```
self.write = ScrolledText(self.maintextFrame,
                          justify(CENTER),
                          width = 100, height = 35, relief = SUNKEN,
```

That's not how you pass a keyword argument `justify` with value `CENTER`; you're passing a positional argument, with value `justify(CENTER)`. So, Python tries to calculate `justify(CENTER)` by looking for a function named `justify`, doesn't find one, and raises a `NameError`.

Moving it doesn't help, it just means you get a `SyntaxError` before you can even get to the `NameError`, because you've got a positional argument `justify(CENTER)` after the keyword argument `font`, and that's not allowed.

The right way to do it is the same way you're passing all the other keyword arguments in the very next line:

```
self.write = ScrolledText(self.maintextFrame,
                          justify = CENTER,
                          width = 100, height = 35, relief = SUNKEN,
```

---

By the way changing the justification to `CENTER` isn't going to change anything from left-aligned to right-aligned; it's going to change it from left-aligned to centered. Are you sure you didn't want `RIGHT`?

---

Once you've fixed the syntax problems, you've got a new problem, which *is* related to tkinter. The `ScrolledText` class just passes through its keyword params to the `Text` class, and the `Text` widget doesn't have a `justify` parameter.

If you read [the docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm), `justify` is used as a tag associated with a range of text, not with the widget. So, you have to use `tag_config` with the `justify` property to create a named tag config, then you can apply it to ranges of text inside the widget, as the examples show. So:

```
self.write.tag_config('justified', justify=RIGHT)
self.write.insert(INSERT, 'Ancients of Mu-Mu', 'justified')
```

And of course this directly answers your other question:

> How can I change the justification of specific lines in the ScrolledText widget in Tkinter?

Either insert them with the right tag in the first place, or select them and apply the tag after the fact.

Comment: I added `justify = CENTER` to my code, but simply got another error. I am running python 2.7.3, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

What maybe confusing people is that the documentation at http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm, referred to above, does in fact list `justify` as an option for the Text widget and maybe there was at one time, (seems like an option a text widget should have) but the documentation at http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/text.htm does not list a `justify` option, only the `-justify` tag. Note that a Label widget can handle multi-line text and does have a `-justify` option.

Comment: No, that documentation doesn't list justify as an option for the widget. It _does_ list it as an option for tags, however. Search for the word "justify" and the only place it appears is on the section related to tags. The page very clearly states "The following options are used with tag_config to specify the visual style for text using a certain tag."