# Tkinter -- how to horizontally center canvas text?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm working on a function in a UI class that is a config window, it displays the logo of the program and has an updating text at the bottom telling you what it's loading, etc.  This is what I have so far:

```
    self.window = "config"
    self.windowWidth = 340
    self.windowHeight = 270
    infoText = "Configuring Kh..."
    self.root = tk.Tk()
    self.root.geometry("%dx%d+400+400" % (self.windowWidth, self.windowHeight))
    self.root.title("Kh Control v1.1 starting...")
    logo = tk.PhotoImage(file="KhLogo.gif")
    mainPanel = tk.Canvas(self.root, width=self.windowWidth, height=self.windowHeight)
    mainPanel.image = logo
    mainPanel.pack()
    mainPanel.create_image(0, 0, image=logo, anchor="nw")
    mainPanel.create_text(0,200, text=infoText, anchor="nw", fill="yellow")
    return
```

I'd like the text in infoText to be centered horizontally and offset vertically about 200px down.  The vertical offset works fine, but I can't figure out how to center the text horizontally.

I started by trying the age old ((width / 2) - (str length / 2)) but then realized that each letter isn't 1px.  And anchor = "center" seems to only put half the text off the left side of the screen.

I'm very new to Python (only a few days now) so if I'm missing something obvious, that's why.

EDIT: and in case it wasn't obvious, this text will change so I can't just make an absolute decision on the offsets, it has to change with the text

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out after scrounging through the canvas reference.

There is a method for a canvas called bbox that returns a tuple containing (x1, y1, x2, y2) of the area an item takes up.  I got those coords, drew up a function to find the px length of it, divided it by 2 and subtracted it from the window width.  Then I used canvas.move to change the x offset using the number the function returned.

```
    def findXCenter(self, canvas, item):
      coords = canvas.bbox(item)
      xOffset = (self.windowWidth / 2) - ((coords[2] - coords[0]) / 2)
      return xOffset
```

The main part is here:

```
    textID = mainPanel.create_text(0,0, text=infoText, anchor="nw", fill="yellow")
    xOffset = self.findXCenter(mainPanel, textID)
    mainPanel.move(textID, xOffset, 0)
```

Hopefully my hours of searching for this answer will help someone later on.

Comment: Yes, your answer will work, but the much easier method is to remove the `anchor="nw"` attribute of your code because the default is `anchor="center"`. With the latter you just have to pass the coordinates you want to have as the center of your text without any additional computations.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the `justify` parameter?
Often `center` is used with non-text objects.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15016161/3900967 might provide some insight.

Comment: I'll try when I get home.  This is a canvas object, not a text object, so I'm not sure it has a justify param.  I picked canvas create text because it's allows for transparent background on text.

Comment: I tried it, it simply center justifies on the anchor which is nw so all that is displayed is the lower right quadrant of the text at the top left corner of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the position of the text using the first part of the .create_text() method.
see http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_text.html

To make this position horizontialy center to the window use self.windowWidth / 2 as the x cordinate

By default the text is anchored to center around the given position.
(.create_text will default to anchor="CENTER")

You will also want to remove the anchor="nw" as this will make your text display down and to the right of the position given

As such your updated code should be.

```
self.window = "config"
self.windowWidth = 340
self.windowHeight = 270
infoText = "Configuring Kh..."
self.root = tk.Tk()
self.root.geometry("%dx%d+400+400" % (self.windowWidth, self.windowHeight))
self.root.title("Kh Control v1.1 starting...")
logo = tk.PhotoImage(file="KhLogo.gif")
mainPanel = tk.Canvas(self.root, width=self.windowWidth, height=self.windowHeight)
mainPanel.image = logo
mainPanel.pack()
mainPanel.create_image(0, 0, image=logo, anchor="nw")
mainPanel.create_text(self.windowWidth/2,200, text=infoText, fill="yellow")
return
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `anchor="center"` method to align your text that created inside the canvas using `canvas.create_text` method

try following example code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=400, height=300)
canvas.pack()

text = canvas.create_text(200, 150, text="Hello World!", anchor="center")

root.mainloop()
```