# Justify line in text Tkinter

Tags: python, text, tkinter

I'm trying to build a Bot who's responding to the user question, I would like to display the user question on the right side of the Frame and the Bot answer to the left side. I've read a post about justify in text with the tag ([How to set justification on Tkinter Text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014980/how-to-set-justification-on-tkinter-text-box)) but I can't apply that on my code, and I'm not familiar with the tags at all. Can you please help me, what am I doing wrong  ? (If this isn't clear please tell me)

Here is my code :

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

ia_answers= "test\n"
input_frame = LabelFrame(window, text="User :", borderwidth=4)
input_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, side=BOTTOM)
input_user = StringVar()
input_field = Entry(input_frame, text=input_user)
input_field.pack(fill=BOTH, side=BOTTOM)

ia_frame = LabelFrame(window, text="Discussion",borderwidth = 15, height = 100, width = 100)
ia_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, side=TOP)

text = Text(ia_frame, state='disabled', text="ok")
text.pack()
text.tag_configure("right", justify='right')
text.tag_add("right", 1.0, "end")
def Enter_pressed(event):
    """Took the current string in the Entry field."""
    input_get = input_field.get()
    input_user.set("")
    text.configure(state='normal')
    text.insert('end', input_get)
    text.insert('end',ia_answers)
    text.configure(state='disabled')

input_field.bind("<Return>", Enter_pressed)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use 2 text widgets?

Comment: I've tried but it would say that I have to create a text widget for each question and answers to have something like : question answer question answers and not question question answer answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two tags -- "left" and "right", set the alignment property, and then apply the tag to the text when you insert it. Strictly speaking you don't need the "left" tag, but it makes the intent of your code a bit clearer.

```
text = Text(ia_frame, state='disabled', text="ok")

text.tag_configure("right", justify="right")
text.tag_configure("left", justify="left")
...
text.insert("end", "this is right-justified\n", "right")
text.insert("end", "this is left-justified\n", "left")
...
```

Comment: I've tried to put that in my code but it doesn't work correctly :     text.insert("end", input_get, "right")
text.insert("end", ia_answers, "left")

Comment: I've found the solution, I've forgot the "\n", it's work now, thank you :)