# How can tkinter justify align text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, text-alignment

I would like to know how can we make tkinter to align text justify.

There's only `CENTER`, `LEFT`, and `RIGHT`.

I would like something like `justify = "JUSTIFY"`
And it seems that it is not implemented.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014980/how-to-set-justification-on-tkinter-text-box

Comment: No no, I already know that. It's more something like this : `justify = justify`

Comment: Then you know the answer. No "cooked" `justify` in `tkinter`. You might want to use a label container with `padx` and `pady` to justify.

Comment: Yes I know the answer i'm only asking for a workaround 

Comment: Well, it depends on the kind of justify you're looking for. "full justify" (flushed left and right) is really impossible. Centered justify can by achieved using padding.

Comment: Well I've got my answer then : its impossible. Thank you :)

Comment: What do you expect setting justify to `"JUSTIFY"` to do? Left? Right? Both? Call a custom function?

Comment: I want to know if a trick exist to make the text justify to both left and right