# How to center the text label in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a window with a fixed shape and put up some text on the GUI. Here is my code:

```
root = Tk()
root.title('Vocab')
root.geometry('700x400')

text = Text(root)
text.insert(INSERT, word)
text.config(state='disabled')
text.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

This code by default alligns the text to the left. How to keep it in the middle?

Here is a picture of my window for reference:

(Any idea why I'm getting those 2 lines on the sides?)
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how-to-set-justification-on-tkinter-text-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014980)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To center the inserted text, configure a tag with `justify='center'`:

```
text.tag_configure("center", justify='center')
```

Then when you insert, add the tag as well:

```
text.insert(INSERT, "jawbone", "center")
```

To have you `Text` widget fill up both sides, use `fill="both"`:

```
text.pack(fill="both",expand=True)
```

Putting it all together:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Vocab')
root.geometry('700x400')

text = tk.Text(root)
text.tag_configure("center", justify='center')
text.insert("1.0", "jawbone", "center")
text.config(state='disabled')
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -2):

You can get the window width and center the text around the width

```
root = Tk()
width = root.winfo_screenwidth() 
root.title('Vocab'.center(width))
```

To edit the text area you can either use the `padx` option for the Text object or center the text itself by setting the total `width` and utilizing the value to center the text around the width, for more information in the options refer the following link

https://web.archive.org/web/20190507210123/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text.html

Also useful would be to understand the layout and grid system to setup the appropriate padding to remove the window padding lines

https://web.archive.org/web/20190429195421/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/layout-mgt.html

Comment: I need to center the text inside the 'text' widget not the title of the window.